# responsive image map rollout repositioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I have:

- responsive image map using plugin
- rollover/out mapped coordinates
- an iFrame within a WordPress template that loads the page containing the image map

What I need:

**The coordinates in my Javascript rollout effect code to ALSO remap according to the browser size, just like the image map itself.**

Code for rollout effect looks something like this:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">


Image1 = new Image(687,587,27)
Image1.src = "https://www.example.com/Test/jan.png"


function zoominjan() {
document.emp.src = Image7.src; return true;
}

function zoomoutjan() {
document.emp.src = Image1.src; return true;
}

function originaljan() {
document.emp.src = Image7.src; return true; 
}

</script>
```

In the body of the page:

```
<img usemap="#image-map" src="all2.png" name="emp" id="wotnot">
<map name="image-map">
  <area shape="circle" coords="485,226,10" onMouseUp="zoomoutjan()" onMouseOver="zoomoutjan()" onMouseOut="originaljan()">
```

Any ideas how to get the rollout effect to also be responsie like the map, whilst still being functional within an iFrame in WordPress?

Much appreciation for any guidance.

SA

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a plugin and added custom code using the API. 
The plugin I used was: https://codecanyon.net/item/image-map-pro-for-wordpress-interactive-image-map-builder/2826664   I will likely attempt a home-grown solution to this at some point, but the plugin worked quite well after you got past some of the more annoying installation aspects. Instructions for a full image changeout are in the documentation but there is an extra apostrophe in the example, so be careful when implementing.